# How did the team get the number of the supervisors phone in S01E05?

Tags: plot-explanation, mr-robot

In Mr Robot, S01E05, the team attempt to social engineer Steel Mountain. When the supervisor they were expecting doesn't turn up, they alter their plan. Where does the team get the number of the supervisor?

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken they get it through her husband, the supervisor has only 1 contact listed (her husband) in all her online information. They went through her husband who apparently had more information online, including his medical records which most likely stated he was expecting results on a test or something.

They found her number most likely as first contact on the list of the medical record.

Comment: Why would the supervisor have her husbands number listed in her online info? How did they access the medical records? They didn't just hack a hospital in minutes? Am I missing something!

Comment: @Pioneer not her husbands number, husbands name. They did a search on the husband and probably led to other things, but at the end of that part she got a text or a phone call (can't remember) stating that it's what we feared, which is the usual statement you get while waiting for results from a test (self experience). Maybe they got the information about his medical history from all his texts in his phone (seeing as they found his number).

Comment: they found his number where then? They wouldn't have time to hack phone services to see texts? How did they get the supervisors number (maybe through the info page).

Comment: Okay step by step, they found her name, they found 1 contact linked to that name (her husband), they followed her husbands name on the internet (he might have mentioned something about sickness on his facebook, twitter, linkedin, etc, this was even before whatsapp encrypted messages so maybe hacked his whatsapp account). He most likely has his wifes number somewhere noted or email address or number from whatsapp. You do know information is easy to find even if you aren't a hacker. So imagine being a hacker, you would have backdoors everywhere for quick info access.

Comment: thanks, sorry, I'm tired, and really need to rewatch season 1

Comment: @Pioneer thats cool man, I need to rewatch that scene that's for sure, feel like I could have explained it alot better :) I will come back if this needs editing.